# Want to use use class name into a before element

Tags: html, css

I don't know if the name of a CSS class can be placed using the "content" of a :: before element in every p tag like so:

```
 <p class="roboto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

.roboto::before {
         content: "p[class] ";
         font-weight: bold;
}
```

The result should be something like this:

> **roboto** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.

Comment: That's a pretty weird request, but there's a great answer for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using content in combination with attr. Here's a demo to show you how it would work.

```css
.roboto::before {
    content: attr(class);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p class="roboto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

The important part is

```
content: attr(class);
```

The attr function is really powerful and can take any attr of an element. 
You can also do more things than just use the class. Here's two more examples.

```css
#roboto::before {
    content: attr(id);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

a::before {
    content: attr(href);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p id="roboto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
<a href="http://google.com">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</a>
```

For more reading about the attr function have a look at this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

If the reason you want to do this is to store data I would suggest that you use a data- attribute instead of storing this in a class.

```css
.roboto::before {
    content: attr(data-class);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p data-class="robot-data" class="roboto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

Comment: A+ for recommending the `data-*` attribute and helping him avoid storing data in the `class` attribute.

Comment: @stenehall can I set a word from class name, eg:- if class names are "language-css", "language-html", etc in this case I want to pass the content as the word after the "-".